# Asp.net Mvc - How to generate Urls of main application from admin application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an eCommerce portal which has two applications, main and admin.

I have to generate few links in admin which would take user to main application. Can I use the main application's routeConfig in admin to generate main's url.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try This anchor tag for redirecting to main application from Admin Area..

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
```

Comment: <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple place any key URLs including the main site's URL/domain in the admin's web.config as an AppSetting key, e.g.

`<add key="MainSite.BaseUrl" value="http://www.site.com" />`

and reference it from there using

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainSite.BaseUrl"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("AdminRouteName", new {action="action", controller="controller", id=123})">linkname</a>
```